# Appeal for SIMPLE examples for fusion tables users eg. mouseover rollover

Tags: google-fusion-tables

On behalf of all the fusion tables keeners who love mapping, can adapt a good script, but are NOT PROGRAMMERS -- journalists and historians and all the rest of the users who are like me...

Just got a group message from Rebecca (GOOGLE rep for FUSION TABLES) announcing it is now possible to "Enable mouseover event on Fusion Table map layer".

She gave this link as a demo: http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/mouseover-jsonp.html

My question: why do these examples have to be so convoluted? This particular table has everything in it but the kitchen sink -- over three dozen columns in the table, with 177 entries -- and the script includes a piece to exclude Antarctica from the rollover effect. (Is that an inside joke?)

Why not work with a simple fusion table with the minimum number of columns, using the simplest, cleanest version of the script to make the effect work? Or 2-3 versions of the example featuring different approaches?

I come to Stackoverflow because this is where Google refers us for support. If I'm wrong and it's not an inclusive forum, not a place for people with less than professional levels of programming skill, just say so.

Me, I have a map with polygons. I'd like to include the mouseover effect that changes the  look of the polygon and border when rolled over. Simple. Forget Antarctica.

If that requres special columns in the fusion table, that should be mentioned somewhere.

Apologies for the rant. I've spent many hours trying to untangle examples and plug in my own table. It shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: The problem with creating examples for FusionTables is that the data in your table is defined by you, what columns exist, what columns have data to be displayed, what the name of the column containing the geographic information is.  If you had provided a reference to your table, someone could help you, but the result of that help probably wouldn't apply to the next person that wants to do the same thing.  The table referred to in that example is one of the publicly available FusionTables containing the Natural Earth data set.

Comment: The geographic information in the Natural Earth data set is in a column named kml_4326

Answer (score 0):

Another option for tooltips is this library:

http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/

http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/docs/reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your notes. The FUSION TIPS demo is a nice simple example easily understood. However, I want to understand the mouseover highlighting example discussed above. So let's use the same John's Pizza Chain fusion table, found here: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=15UY2pgiz8sRkq37p2TaJd64U7M_2HDVqHT3Quw How would you apply the mouseover highlighting technique to this much simpler table? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It works the same way (the fusion tips demo has two options, GViz and the same JSONP mechanism that is used in that example)  & you specifically asked for a simple example.

Comment: Very sorry, I'm not making myself clear. I would really like to see a simple example of how to use THIS script:  http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontables/mouseover-jsonp.html

And more generally, I would ask that the Google support folks always think abut simplicity and clarity when providing examples for users. As I said up top, lots of teachers and journalist-types and others want to use fusion tables. We can adapt a good script, but we are not programmers. Many thanks, Wendy

Comment: Looking at the source for that example, it is pretty simple, I certainly can't simplify it further without knowing how you are trying to use it or what trouble you are having applying it to your application, and not being associated with Google, can't help with the other part of your question.